# How to Use Canvas in UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to use Canvas in UserControl in WPF but there isn't any Canvas in

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
```

i want to change this second userControl to Canvas
what should i do?
With Respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` class is in the assembly `PresentationFramework.dll`, so you should add reference to this assembly ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.100).aspx)):

> Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls
>
> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
>
> XMLNS for XAML:
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation,
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation

[image]

**UPDATE**

1) You should change this value in code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : Canvas
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

2) You should change it in XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Class="MyApp.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

</Canvas>
```

Comment: this dll there is in my Reference,   i update my question please take a look at my question again please

Comment: In code-behind you have partial class (`public partial class UserControl1 : Canvas`) so between XAML and code-behind those types should be the same.